# Fragment or geometry shaders: Count rendered triangles?

Tags: performance, opengl, geometry, triangle-count

`gl_PrimitiveID` seems to count the number of primitives rendered. This seems to be available via both fragment and geometry shaders.

Would this be an accurate count of rendered triangles in the view frustum (assuming only tris, since the primitive ID also applies to lines and points) as opposed to the whole scene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `gl_PrimitiveID` variable is output from a geometry shader and fed to the fragment shader. If no geometry shader is present, then the fragment shader's `gl_PrimitiveID` is the number of primitives that have been processed in the current rendering call. That is, it's the number of points/lines/triangles that are sent through the vertex processing pipeline. If you call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 33);` you will get a `gl_PrimitiveID` on the half-open range [0, 11).

If a geometry shader *is* present, then `gl_PrimitiveID` takes on whatever value you output from your GS. If a GS is present and you *don't* write to the value, then the fragment shader gets an undefined value. Note that you could just copy `gl_PrimitiveIDIn` into `gl_PrimitiveID` for each vertex you write to get the standard OpenGL behavior.

In short, no, it does not take into account view frustum culling. Not unless your GS actually does view frustum culling per-triangle (and I would advise it).

Comment: Will the figure returned by gl_PrimitiveID include backfaces, or will those be left out?

Comment: @Nick: I didn't leave any wiggle room when I said, "*it's the number of points/lines/triangles that are sent through the vertex processing pipeline. If you call `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 33);` you will get a `gl_PrimitiveID` on the half-open range [0, 11).*"

Comment: So much for clear explanations. I will ask elsewhere. Thanks. I would also ask that in future, if you won't offer a direct explanation, don't bother answering at all. Let someone else answer my questions instead.

Comment: @Nick: How is that not clear? I offered a direct and *complete* explanation of the exact behavior of `gl_PrimitiveID`, which is what you asked for. That explanation does not include backface culling, viewport culling, triangle clipping, `GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD`, or *any other thing* in OpenGL that would prevent a primitive from being drawn. Therefore, none of those things affect `gl_PrimitiveID`.

Comment: Now that's an answer. You assumed that I know what will or won't be passed down the pipeline -- I don't. Hence my asking the question re backfaces. I find your OpenGL answers to often (not always) be less to-the-point than they need be, hence my above request. Perhaps this is something to consider, as I note that you answer many, many such questions here and on gamedev. I hope this will be taken as constructive criticism. Also, thank you for updating your answer. Accepted.